Problem in Understanding the Geometrical Interpretation of a First-Order PDE
I was studying about the  "Geometrical Interpretation of a First-Order PDE" from the book,  "Linear Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers" (in Fourth Edition) written by Tyn Myint-U and Lokenath Debnath.
I was having some problems in understanding the following text given there in Section 2.4:
To investigate the geometrical content of a first-order, partial differential equation, we begin with a general, quasi-linear equation
$ 
a(x,y,u)u_x + b(x,y,u)u_y - c(x,y,u) = 0. 
$
We assume that the possible solution of this equation is in the form $u = u(x,y)$ or in an implicit form
$
f(x,y,u) \equiv u(x,y) - u = 0 
$
which represents a possible solution surface in $(x,y,u)$ space. This is often called an integral surface of the equation. At any point $(x,y,u)$ on the solution surface, the gradient vector $\nabla f = (f_x, f_y, f_u) = (u_x, u_y, -1)$ is normal to the solution surface. Clearly, the equation can be written as the dot product of two vectors
$
au_x + bu_y - c = (a,b,c) \cdot (u_x,u_y,-1) = 0. 
$
This clearly shows that the vector $(a,b,c)$ must be a tangent vector of the integral surface at the point $(x,y,u)$, and hence, it determines a direction field called the characteristic direction or Monge axis. This direction is of fundamental importance in determining a solution of the equation.
To summarize, we have shown that $f(x,y,u) = u(x,y) - u = 0,$ as a surface in the $(x,y,u)$-space, is a solution of the equation if and only if the direction vector field $(a,b,c)$ lies in the tangent plane of the integral surface $f(x,y,u) = 0$ at each point $(x,y,u)$, where $\nabla f \neq 0.$

However, I don't get how did they write,

This clearly shows that the vector $(a,b,c)$ must be a tangent vector of the integral surface at the point $(x,y,u)$, and hence, it determines a direction field called the characteristic direction or Monge axis.

I get that, $au_x + bu_y - c = (a,b,c) \cdot (u_x,u_y,-1) = 0.$ But this only means that, $(a,b,c)$ is perependicular to $\nabla f$ (we consider $\nabla f$ at each point $(x,y,u),$) which further means, that $(a,b,c)$ is parallel to the tangent plane of $u=u(x,y)$ passing through the point $(x,y,u).$ But this does in no way suggest that $(a,b,c)$ lies in the tangent plane of $u$ passing through the point $(x,y,u).$ Neither does it suggest that $(a,b,c)$ be a tangent vector to the surface $u$ at the point $(x,y,u).$
My point can be better illustrated with the 3D image below:

This image shows a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4,$ two planes $z=2,$ and $z=4.$ The plane $z=2$ is a tangent plane of the sphere passing through the point $(0,0,2).$ The plane $z=4$ is a plane that is parallel to the tangent plane $z=2.$
Suppose, in our case, $f(x,y,z)=0=u-u(x,y)$ is the sphere in the 3D image above. Then, $\nabla f(0,0,2)$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane $z=2.$ Now, the vector $(a,b,c)$ may lie on the plane $z=2.$ Or it may not be. The vector $(a,b,c)$ may also lie in some plane parallel to the tangent plane (,i.e. $z=2$) say, on $z=4.$
But as the text suggests, $(a,b,c)$ will not only lie on the tangent plane but also, will be a tangent vector to the sphere at the point $(0,0,2)$ (considering our example). This seems absurd to me.
Any help regarding this apparent issue will be greatly appreciated.

Usually, a vector is only a direction: it is meaningless to say that it "belongs to a plane". And in fact the text doesn't say that.

@Intelligentipauca Vectors do have orientations in space, right? Please do consider seeing the edit in the original post. I tried adding more clarity to my doubts.

Your view that two vectors with the same magnitude and direction can be different because applied at different point in space is not right (see here). You must think instead to a vector field, which is the right thing in this case.

@Intelligentipauca I am not saying that, "two vectors with the same magnitude and direction can be different because applied at different point in space" but what I am saying that when they say, "This clearly shows that the vector $(a,b,c)$ must be a tangent vector of the integral surface at the point $(x,y,u)$" they simply suggest that the vector $(a,b,c)$ is passing through the point $(x,y,u)$ and touches only at these point with the solution surface (, otherwise the word tangent vector wouldn't have been used for $(a,b,c)$).

But this might not be the case, it might be parallel to the tangent vector at the point $(x,y,u)$ of the solution surface.

Again, a vector cannot "pass" through a point, it is not a line! A vector only gives a direction and a magnitude. When they write "This clearly shows that the vector (,,) must be a tangent vector of the integral surface at the point (,,)" they mean just that: vector $(a,b,c)$ is parallel to the plane tangent to the surface at $(x,y,u)$.
